# How to play multiple random songs in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, audio

So I'd like to have a button in the center of my page to initiate a playlist of randomly selected songs.  Once the button is clicked, it should disappear and an audio control window spanning the entire width of the screen should pop up along the bottom of the screen.  I've got five mp3 files I'm playing around with.  I currently have a start, pause, and resume button, but they're freestanding ugly buttons.  Here's a bit of code I have:

```
<audio id="blue">
    <source src="blue.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio id="cigar">
    <source src="cigar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio id="immigrant">
    <source src="immigrant.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio id="monkey">
    <source src="monkey.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio id="money">
    <source src="money.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script>
    var a1 = document.getElementById("blue"); 
    var a2 = document.getElementById("cigar"); 
    var a3 = document.getElementById("immigrant"); 
    var a4 = document.getElementById("monkey"); 
    var a5 = document.getElementById("money"); 
    var x;

    function playAudio() { 
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
        if(num == 1){
            x = a1;
            x.play();
        }else if(num == 2){
            x = a2;
            x.play();
        }else if(num == 3){
            x = a3;
            x.play();
        }else if(num == 4){
            x = a4;
            x.play();
        }else if(num == 5){
            x = a5;
            x.play();
        }
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
    x.pause(); 
} 


function resumeAudio() {
    x.play();
}


</script>
```

I'm just completely lost as to how I can incorporate all this into something like this:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="fileName.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

One of the major issues is that I don't know of a way to queue up a song (randomly) and have it play once the previous song ends.  I did some Googling but I either couldn't understand what I saw, or it wasn't quite what I need.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:
HTML:

```
<audio id="player" controls></audio>
```

JavaScript:

```
const audioSources = ["blue.mp3", "cigar.mp3", "immigrant.mp3", "monkey.mp3", "money.mp3"];
const player = document.getElementById("player");
function playAudio() {
    let audioSource = audioSources[Math.floor(Math.random() * audioSources.length)];
    player.src = audioSource;
};
player.addEventListener('ended', playAudio);
playAudio(); // start audio playing immediately
```

Tell me if that works.

Comment: It doesn't, although I'm not sure if I've implemented it properly.  My page is now entirely composed of the code you've written, excluding a navigational bar and a title.

Comment: Do you know why it isn't working? Perhaps you should change my `audioSources` to have absolute paths rather than just relative paths.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working.  I deleted all my HTML and JavaScript, then put yours in.  I think the relative paths should be fine, as all files share the same folder, but I'll give it a shot.  Again, I didn't support any of this with my own code, but maybe I should have?

Comment: @RobertMoore `let audioSource = audioSources[Math.floor(Math.random() * audioSources.length);` missing `]`

Comment: @TfarcrawIIV Try copy paste it again, it was missing an end bracket.

Comment: @zer00ne I've copy-pasted again, but it still doesn't work.  The audio player shows up, but upon clicking the play button, nothing happens.  Is the HTML supposed to be literally just that, or do I need to add anything more?

Comment: @TfarcrawIIV http://embed.plnkr.co/KkyrQaaWedN6m8lNvWXl/ see comments in the demo.

Comment: @zer00ne Thank you!  I've copy-pasted what you've written, substituting in my own audio files, but it doesn't go to the next song. It instead stops at the end of the song.  When I click the play button again it starts the song over.

Comment: @TfarcrawIIV When you substituted with your own files, did you replace the value of `base` with your own path? Then use only filenames in the `playlist` array? Are all of the files in one directory? Can you give me the urls of at least 2 of your files?

Comment: @zer00ne I'm doing everything locally on my drives, so I don't have a URL, but the folder pathway for the songs is: 'C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Music\songs'.  Al the songs are there.  I've done this: src='songs/blue.mp3'  and var base = 'songs';

Comment: @TfarcrawIIV when using local files the syntax for path is different: `file:///C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Music/songs/blue.mp3` so `var base = "file:///C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Music/songs/"` and `var playlist = ["blue.mp3", "monkey.mp3", ...];`

Comment: @zer00ne Ah, okay.  Thanks.  So, should the audio src look like this: src='file:///C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Music/songs/blue.mp3'?

Comment: @TfarcrawIIV Yes, but the code will not operate as expected if you use the source like that literally. If you intend to play just that file then yes, but if you intend to play the playlist randomly or straight, then you need to have the `base + playlist[i]` combo setup as described in my last comment.

Comment: @zer00ne I'm sorry, but I'm really having trouble understanding.  What should the source path look like in my audio HTML element?  My base and playlist variables look exactly like what you've listed.

Comment: The audio tag doesn't need a src attribute unless you want to auto start or preload a file.

Comment: @zer00ne I removed the pathway for the src tag and removed the src tag completely.  In each case, the audio control bar greys out, and I can't play anything.

Comment: I don't think I can help because it boils down to whether your urls have a typo, or there's something in your setup  is interfering. I'd have to first verify from my endpoint as to whether or not your files are accessible which is impossible since your are just using your computer locally. I don't remember if you told me if the demo I showed worked for you, just playing I don't mean if it works after you copy it and place it elsewhere. http://embed.plnkr.co/KkyrQaaWedN6m8lNvWXl/